# GAE/Python: collection_name not working with Polymodel?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm having trouble using db.ReferenceProperty with PolyModel in GAE.  If I have two models derived from a base PolyModel, and each one has a reference to another "container" model, the collections on the container contain both PolyModels, not just the one as you would expect.  Here is a test case that shows the problem:

```
from google.appengine.ext import  db
from google.appengine.ext.db import polymodel

class MyContainer(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(default='mycontainer', multiline=False)

class MyBaseModel(polymodel.PolyModel):    
    name = db.StringProperty(default='mybasemodel', multiline=False)

class MyModelOne(MyBaseModel):
    container = db.ReferenceProperty(MyContainer, collection_name='model_ones')

class MyModelTwo(MyBaseModel):     
    container = db.ReferenceProperty(MyContainer, collection_name='model_twos')

print "Beginning test.\n"
c = MyContainer(name="Container")
c.put()
one = MyModelOne(name="One", container=c)
two = MyModelTwo(name="Two", container=c)
one.put()
two.put()

print "Ones:"
for o in c.model_ones:
    print o.name
print "\nTwos:"
for o in c.model_twos:
    print o.name
```

And the output:

```
Beginning test.

Ones:
One
Two

Twos:
One
Two
```

Am I missing something in setting up my ReferenceProperties, or is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So looking at the [SDK source](http://www.google.com/codesearch#Qx8E-7HUBTk/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py&type=cs&l=3701), it appears that _ReverseReferenceProperty (which translates collections into Query objects) doesn't make any attempt to handle PolyModels. There are a few related complaints on the issue tracker, [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1035) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2336).

IMO, if this is a known limitation it ought to be mentioned somewhere in the PolyModel docs.

**Edit**: The collection-less workaround would be something like this:

`for o in MyModelOne.all().filter('container =', c):`

Comment: Thanks, that confirms what I'm seeing.  I agree that the docs are lacking, I might submit a bug on this. Your filter works, that is a solution for me.  In my sample above, how would I get all MyBaseModel, without the related MyModelOne and MyModelTwo?  `MyBaseModel.all().filter("_class !=", "MyModelOne")` does not work.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. Filtering for kind = MyBaseModel or class = MyBaseModel will match all subclasses. `filter("class !=", "MyModelOne")` should exclude MyModelOne, but you'd need multiple inequality filters to exclude all child classes. A workaround would be to manually include the class name as a default value on the base model, and set a different default value on child models. Then you could filter on that.